# How to exclude some files when build on vue-cli3 project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have a project created by **vue-cli3**. Now I have some files that I use during development, but I don't need them in a production environment.

eg: 
I put a file named test.html into **/public**, and I could access it using http://localhost:8080/test.html (assume project running at http://localhost:8080). When I generate a production version, I don't want this file got included in **/dist**(default output dir).

All files under /public will be copyed to **/dist/static**, but it is not the result I expect.

How can I do to get access some files when developing but don't get them involved in production?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?